# Cannot install cvxpy with python 3.8

Tags: python, pip, cvxpy

I have tried installing cvxpy (https://www.cvxpy.org/install/) for python. I use Python 3.8 for all my projects and am not to fond of making virtual environments where i use 3.7. Does anyone have a fix for using cvxpy on python 3.8 (I am using windows)?

Thanks!

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
ommand: 'AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kehvj2di\\osqp\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kehvj2di\\osqp\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1u4al7gt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
cwd: AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kehvj2di\osqp\

-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18362.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:

        MSBuild.exe

      to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

        The system cannot find the file specified



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-kehvj2di/osqp/osqp_sources/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    The system cannot find the file specified
    CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: MSBuild.exe osqpstatic.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /v:m &&
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'osqp_sources\\build\\out\\Release\\osqp.lib'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kehvj2di\\osqp\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kehvj2di\\osqp\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1u4al7gt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Done, forgot that.

Comment: Note that you could also download and install the `whl` file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxpy), but setting up your built tools correctly is still something worth doing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not seem to be the Python version, but lack of build tools. Install [Microsoft Visual Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16) and make sure they are on the PATH (so that `conda` can execute `MSBuild.exe`).

Build Tools [installation instructions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4GsMXCRaSSIOWpYQkstajlYZ0tPVkNQSElmTWh1dXFaYkJr/view) from `cvxpy` (in pptx).

Comment: I have these installed in the exact same way as my colleagues who use Python 3.7, how would you suggest putting them on PATH?

Comment: How did you install them? Did you use the link in the `cvxpy` docs for downloading them?

Comment: Yes I have used that one, but previously I have also done the visual studio 2019, in which you can also get the build tools.


cvxpy says: CVXPY has the following dependencies:

Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, or 3.7.

Comment: @Bart Can you check if `MSBuild.exe` is on your PATH? Can you execute it from the command line? `cvxpy` requires Python 3.5 or greater https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/master/setup.py#L71 README is misleading.

Comment: So I have it on my path, it sitll does not work though.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

>MSBuild.exe
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like one of dependencies did not compile. Can you check `AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-kehvj2di/osqp/osqp_sources/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`?